# Word2Vec model is not training, input sentences tried with both sequence of sentence and tokenized words in list

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I went through the word2vec tutorial and was able to train with given example data of Text8Corpus. [Tutorial link](https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial) But when I tried to test on custom data, model is not training. The input are in unicode string format in python list. And min_count is also set to 1. Since it was not training in above input format, I tried to check type of input from the given tutorial, but I receive the format as this: class 'gensim.models.word2vec.Text8Corpus'. So not sure how to train my custom data of unicode string sentences in a list. Can anyone please guide me in right direction ?

> Example of the input : [[u'SENTENCE_START', u'dont', u'let', u'him', u'treat', u'you', u'like', u'garbage', u'SENTENCE_END']]

```
sentences_clean = []
data = pandas.read_excel('from my folder/3_captions.xlsx', parse_cols = "A")
sentences = data.iloc[:, 0].tolist()

for line in sentences:
  line = re.sub(r"""["?,$!]|'(?!(?<! ')[ts])""", "", line)
  line = re.sub(r"\.", "", line) 
  line = line.lower().replace("'", "")
  sentences_clean.append(line)

tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences_clean]

import gensim, logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
model_word2vec = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences_clean, min_count=1, size=300, workers=4)
model_word2vec.save('/Users/rajesh/Documents/word2vec')
print (model_word2vec.similarity('freudian','slip'))
```

that's all there is to train to word2vec I understand from tutorial and example ? But this below tutorial works.

```
sentences = word2vec.Text8Corpus('/Users/rajesh/Downloads/text8')
model_word2vec = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1, size=20)
print (model_word2vec.similarity('queen','woman'))
>>> 0.659536897647
```

Comment: Does it give any errors, or is the problem w2v not giving you correct output? Nonetheless I believe you need to tokenize your sentences first.

Comment: It didn't give any errors. I also tried with tokenizing the sentences with nltk. Tokenized input then was : [u'SENTENCE_START', u'i', u'guess', u'i', u'just', u'dont', u'understand', u'why', u'i', u'always', u'have', u'to', u'be', u'the', u'fall', u'guy', u'SENTENCE_END']

Comment: I didn't pop any errors, also when I tried to check word similarity, I received the word is not in vocab error. But I don't think the model was trained even to begin with.

Comment: Hmm tokenized corpus works for me, can you post the related parts of your code in question. The link you gave doesn't lead to a tutorial.

Comment: The code works for me, bear in mind you are training for 5 iterations. Maybe you can try and see what happens with more training. You can call `model_word2vec.train(clean_sentences)` or give `iter = 20` parameter to model when initializing. To query similarity or anything you need to have that word in your vocabulary you can check that by `if 'freudian' in model_word2vec`.

Comment: How can I print and see what all the words are trained in model_word2vec ? when checking, word 'freudian' isn't in the vocabulary it says but it is present in my tokenized input. So confused.

Comment: You can use `model_word2vec.wv.vocab` to print out your model's vocabulary. Which will return a dictionary.

Comment: Glad it helped, I'm supposed to be working right now so couldn't reply in time =)

Answer (score 1):

How do you know it's "not training"?

Are you sure you want to provide `sentences_clean` to Word2Vec, as in your shown code, rather than the `tokenized_sentences` list?

(If `sentences_clean` is a list-of-strings, each string given to Word2Vec will look like a list-of-characters, and the only 'words' learned by your Word2Vec model will be single-characters.)